# How to set custom email settings automatically

Tags: email, ssl, mail-server

Im trying to change how email clients auto add my mail server settings. How would i change the default settings for my mail server to custom values that i set? 
Thunderbird and other mail clients retrieve the mail servers settings whether its SSL, TLS, Server name, so on. How would i make it so when someone uses my email server, it automatically uses SSL and sets the incoming an outgoing setting to my preference.

Comment: Off-topic, voting to move to ServerFault (since it's somewhat related to server configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What to do to make Thunderbird use automatic settings is described on this page:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration

Comment: Thx this was mostly wat i was looking for. Didnt see anything about security tho, The mail server is correct but it still defaults to TLS id rather it use SSL. anyway to make it default to SSL?

Comment: You're certainly talking about [implicit SSL/TLS v.s. explicit SSL/TLS (`STARTTLS`)](http://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187). I think the socketType element should be `SSL` for implicit SSL/TLS and `STARTTLS` for explicit.